# Showing that if $f''(x) = 0$, $f(x) = ax+b$ without integrating

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Assume that $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is two times differentiable with $f''(x)=0$
>   for all $x \in A$, with $A$ an interval.
>
> Show, (not by integration), that $f$ is of the form $f(x) = ax + b$ for some constants $a, b$.

My answer:
I will use the Mean Value Theorem:

1. Take $x,y \in A, x<y$. Applying the Mean Value Theorem on $[x,y]$ gives:
   $$f''(c)=\frac{f'(y)-f'(x)}{y-x}$$ for some $c \in A$. If $f''(x)=0 $ for all $x \in A$, then $f''(c)=0$, wich means that $f''(c)=\frac{f'(y)-f'(x)}{y-x}= 0$, which implies that $f'(y)-f'(x)=0$. So $f'(y)=f'(x)$. Set $k$ equal to this common value. Because x and y are arbitrary, it follows that $f'(x)=a$ for all $x \in A$
2. We are now given that $f'(x)=a$ for all $x \in A$. This means that, if we take $x,y \in A, x<y, $, by applying the Mean Value Theorem on [x,y], 
   $$f'(c)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$ for some $c \in A$. We know that $f'(x)=a$ for all $x \in A$, which means that $$f'(c)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=a \implies f(y)-f(x)=a(y-x)$$

What's next?

I could also use the definition of derivative, considering:

$$f'(x)=a = \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$

How can I show that $f(x) = ax + b$ ?

Comment: Change to $\,y-x\,$ your denominator in (1)-(2)

Comment: At the end of point 1., you write that $f'(x)=f'(y)=0$ and then you write that $f'(x)=k$ for all $x\in A$. Am I not seeing why those two statements don't conflict? Did you mean to write $f'(x)-f'(y)=0$?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Ty. I updated it. Do you guys know how to go further with this proof? :-)

Comment: If the derivative is the function's rate of change, and the first derivative is a constant, then the second derivative would be the rate of change of a constant which would be zero. Is this not a sufficient proof?

Comment: you can't say $\forall c \in A$. It has to be $\forall c \in ]x,y[$.

Comment: @EmmadKareem No, because this is an exercise from Real Analysis. I have to understand simple things deeply :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the taylor expansion  of $\displaystyle f(x+0) = \sum_{k\ge0}x^k\cfrac {f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} = f(0) + xf'(0)+x^2\cfrac{f''(0)}{2!}+ \cdots$ Since $f''(x) = 0$ then every subsequent derivative is $0$. Thus we have $f(x) = f(0) + xf'(0)$ with $a=f'(0)$ and $b=f(0)$.

> **EDIT:** But the Taylor series of a function does not always converge to the function, in this case the Taylor Series is a polynomial. Check this [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93452/a-question-on-taylor-series-and-polynomial/216587#216587) to see how such functions equal to their Taylor series.

You see, no integration at all. This is one of the most important uses of Taylor Series, solving differential equations. Check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218421/what-are-the-practical-applications-of-the-taylor-series/218430#218430) for futher details.

**Lemme restart your work:** $A = [c,d]$

Given a function $f(x) \in C^2[c,d] \space|\space f''(x) =0,\space \forall x\in[c,d]$. Using the Mean Value Theorem, since the second derivative is $0$ then $f'(x) = a \in [c,d]$.

Using the theorem again on $f'(x)$, we have that  $\forall x\in [c,d], \space \exists b_1\in[c,x]\space |\space f'(b_1)=\cfrac {f(x) - f(c)}{x -c} =a$ and $\exists b_2\in[x,d]\space |\space f'(b_2)=\cfrac {f(d) - f(x)}{d -x} = a$.  Since the function is two times derivable then both the right and left derivative should be equal. Thus we have $f(d) - f(x) = a(d-x)$ and $f(x) - f(c) = a(x-c)$ which implies $$\begin{matrix}
  f(x) = ax +f(d) - ad \\
  f(x) = ax + f(c) - ac
 \end{matrix}$$
Now we have a problem where we have to prove that $f(d) -ad = f(c) -ac$. Assuming it is true then $f(d) -ad = f(c) -ac \space\Rightarrow\space a=\cfrac{f(d)-f(c) }{d-c}$. Since $a= f'(x) = \cfrac{f(d)-f(c) }{d-c}, \space \forall x\in [c,d]$, then our proof is complete and we can conclude that $f(d) -ad = f(c) -ac=b \in [c,d]$ and that $$f(x) = ax +b$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I have to use the theory of derivatives, especially the mean value theorem :)

Comment: check now! I've used the Mean Value Theorem

Comment: very good, thanks!!!

Comment: I'm just asking: Is it clear that the Taylor Series really is equal to the function, i.e. that f is analytical?

Comment: @F'OlaYinka Thanks, now I see it!

Comment: @Hempo: It's probably worth noting that these two proofs are in some sense the same proof expanded differently -- the way you prove Taylor's theorem is by repeatedly applying the MVT to the derivatives of your function...

Answer (score 3):

You're effectively done once you have ${\displaystyle {f(y) - f(x) \over y - x} = a}$. For this can be rewritten as
$$f(y) - f(x) = a(y - x)$$
or just
$$f(x) = ax + ay - f(y)$$
This holds for all $x$ and $y$ in your interval. So you can fix one such $y$, and define $b = ay - f(y)$. Then the above equation is exactly
$$f(x) = ax + b$$
Since this holds for all $x$ in the interval you are done.

---

By the way, if you want to use Taylor series, you can use the form with remainder which says that for fixed $x_0$ in the interior of your interval, for any $x$ in the interval you have
$$f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0) + {1 \over 2}f''(c_x)(x-x_0)^2$$
Here $c_x$ is between $b$ and $x$. Since $f''(c_x) = 0$, this means that for all $x$ you have
$$f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)$$
This is of the form $ax + b$ as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just finish it from your last line. Fix any $y_0$. Then, $f(x) = a(x-y_0) + f(y_0)$ for all $x$, i.e. $f(x)$ is a line.