# A semigroup $X$ is a group iff for every $g\in X$, $\exists! x\in X$ such that $gxg = g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, semigroups

The following could have shown up as an exercise in a basic Abstract Algebra text, and if anyone can give me a reference, I will be most grateful.

Consider a set $X$ with an associative law of composition, not known to have an identity or inverses. Suppose that for every $g\in X$, there is a unique $x\in X$ with $gxg=g$. Show that $X$ is a group.

Note that I’m not asking for a proof (though a really short one would please me!), just some place where this has been published.

Comment: I keep thinking that $gxg=g$ automatically implies $x=g^{-1}$ . . . I just have a feeling this is far too simple. Is it? The more I think about this, the more it confuses me. Isn't that the only possible way that equality holds for this situation? I can't see any other value for $x$ such that this holds for all $g\in X$ and $x\in X$.

Comment: I think Prof. Lubin already knows that this is a true statement (he is not asking us if this is true or not). So people should rethink if they believe they have a counterexample.

Comment: I'm still unsure what is wrong with the example $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with multiplication. There is a unique $x$ such that $gxg=g$ for all $g\in X$, namely $x=(1,1)$, but it isn't a group. Will someone explain if anything is wrong with the counterexample? I would just like to see it if there is something wrong.

Comment: The question is not that $\exists$ ! $x$ such that for all $g$ ..., but that $\forall$ $g$ there exists a unique $x$ such that ... I think you got your order of quantifiers wrong.

Comment: @Clayton Are you confusing "there is an $x$ such that for all $g$" with "for all $g$ there is an $x$"?

Comment: I don't think so. In the example, $x=(1,1)$ is unique, so it works for all $g$. If you think about it for just a little while, you'll see what I mean (I hope). No other element will have the property, since, when multiplied by (1,1), at least one of these coordinates would go to $0$. @leo thanks! I hope so

Comment: @Clayton $(0,1)(0,1)(0,1)=(0,1)=(0,1)(1,1)(0,1)$, failing the uniqueness criterion.

Comment: But $(0,1)(1,1)(0,1)=(0,1)$, so your example doesn't work, I don't think.

Comment: @peoplepower, I don't think the $x$ has to be unique in the sense that no other element works for some, but not others. I think the particular $x$ in question has to work for all $g\in X$, and it's okay if there is an element that fixes itself.

Comment: No, Clayton. Reread the question. For each $g\in X$, there is a unique $x\in X$ (depending on $g$) such that $gxg=g$. This is not the same as there being a unique $x\in X$ such that for each $g\in X$, $gxg=g$.

Comment: I think I see, never mind; I apologize. Thanks for helping my understanding along... :)

Comment: Perhaps this is a record: so far, 5 deleted answers out of 7 tries to this question.

Comment: @DonAntonio Take a look at [this gem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93452/a-question-on-taylor-series-and-polynomial/) :)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I believe this is well-known to those working in regular/inverse semigroups. So well-known in fact that one can even find proofs on the web, e.g. see [this proof on PlanetMath.](https://planetmath.org/acharacterizationofgroups) Alas, I cannot recall the history of this result, though I vaguely recall reading something about such decades ago. For completeness, I reproduce below said common proof (slightly edited).

**Theorem** $\ $ A non-empty semigroup $\,S\,$ is a group if and only if for every $\,x\in S$ there is a unique $y\in S$ such that $\,xyx=x$.

**Proof** $\ (\Leftarrow)\,$   For each $\,x\in S\,$  let $\,x'$ be the unique element of $\,S\,$ such that $\,xx'x=x.\ $  Note  $\,x(\color{#0a0}{x'xx'})x=(xx'x)x'x=x\color{#C00}{x'}x=x,\,$  so, by uniqueness, $\,\color{#0a0}{x'xx'}=\color{#C00}{x}',\,$ hence $\,\color{#0a0}x = \color{#C00}{x}''.$

For all $\,x\in S\,$  the element $\,xx'$ is idempotent $\,(xx')^2=(xx'x)x'=xx'.$ Thus, being nonempty, $S\,$ has at least one idempotent. If $\,i\in S$ is idempotent, then $\,ix =ix\color{#0A0}{(ix)'}ix=ix\color{#C00}{(ix)'i}\:\!ix\,$  so, by uniqueness,  $\color{#C00}{(ix)'i}=\color{#0A0}{(ix)'},$ hence $(ix)'=(ix)'(ix)''(ix)'=\color{#C00}{(ix)'i}x(ix)'=\color{#0A0}{(ix)'}x(ix)'$ so, by uniqueness, $x = (ix)''=ix.\,$  So every idempotent $\,i\,$ is a left identity and, by a symmetry, a right identity. Therefore, $S\,$ has at most one idempotent element. Combined with the previous result, this means that $S\,$ has exactly one idempotent element, denoted $\,e.\,$ We have shown that $\,e\,$ is an identity, and that $\,xx'=e\,$ for each $\,x\in S,$  hence $\,S\,$ is a group.

$(\Rightarrow)\,$ if $\,S\,$ is a group then $\,xyx=x\iff xy=1\iff y = x^{-1},\,$ so $\,y\,$ is unique.
$\ \bf\small QED$

Comment: Thanks! This proof is shorter and more direct than the one I found, too.

Comment: How does one get the idea to consider the inverse of an arbitrary idempotent times x?

Comment: This is the kind of complete correct answer with effort that I love.

Comment: The argument is beautiful and quite natural.

Answer (score 23):

I am just putting some sources here. Bill Dubuque already did all the work:

This book may be of some interest: Mark V. Lawson, *Inverse Semigroups: The Theory of Partial Symmetries*, [at Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=2805q4tFiCkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

I came across this book in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup), which gives some of the history of Inverse Semigroups.

Also, there is [this shorter PDF](http://www.ma.hw.ac.uk/~markl/Ottawa/chap1.pdf) by the author of the book whose link I gave above, and what you state is probably Proposition 2.4 in the notes (although it is stated in a different way) after some other things have already been proved.

Comment: The third link is broken. Could you please update it.