# Proving $G$ to be a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$  be a semigroup and for each $x \in G$ there exists a unique element $y \in G$ such that $xyx = x$. Prove that $G$ is a group.

Since G is a semigroup the properties of a closure and associativity hold, so all we need to prove is the existence of a unique identity and inverse for each element.
For identity, since $xyx = x$ can we say that $yx = e$ and $xy = e$ and since $x \in G$  and $y \in G$ therefore $yx \in G$ and $xy \in G$ and hence $e \in G$. This proves that identity exists.

Again, for inverse, $yx = e$ and $xy = e$ proves that $y = x^{-1}$.

Therefore $G$ is a group.
Can someone please tell me if my approach is correct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $xyx=x$ only shows that $xy$ acts as the identity for multiplying with $x$; it doesn't show that for all $z$ you have $xyz=z$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson oops...sorry let me think it over again.

Comment: Check this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253514/reference-request-for-tricky-problem-in-elementary-group-theory

Comment: @JoshKeneda Thank you! I'll check that out.